# Cannot open files from windows explorer in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I want eclipse to open a file when I double click it in windows explorer. If eclipse is not running and I perform the action it opens just fine. However, if I have eclipse running when I try to open the file I get the following error in eclipse:

[image]

I have set eclipse as the default program to open the files, and it seems that eclipse is getting that message, but it seems to be loosing the path to the file somewhere in the process. I'm completely stumped, as to what setting is causing this.

I have tried altering the eclipse.ini file as indicated in this article [openfilefeature](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse/OpenFileFeature). I changed the lines:
`--launcher.defaultAction
openFile`

to 

`--launcher.defaultAction
--launcher.openFile`

but all that did was make eclipse try to start a whole new instance of the ide instead of opening the file up in the one that was already open.

FYI I'm running on Juno - 4.2.2.M20130204-1200

Comment: As you can see, your Eclipse version is 3.5 years old. Many fixes and improvements have been implemented since then, maybe even including one for your use-case. So please update to most recent (Neon) release first.

Comment: @Mickael It is happening in Neon as well.

Comment: Does the command `eclipse.exe --launcher.openFile <absolute path of file to open>` work from command-line? If it does then it's most likely an issue on Windows configuration side.